# Iterating an object's attributes using dir and getattr rigorously

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to programmatically access all fields of some Python3 object using a combination of `dir` and `getattr`. Pseudocode below:

```
x = some_object()
for i in dir(x):
    print(str(getattr(x, i)))
```

However, the Python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)  on `dir` is VERY vague:

> Note Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases.

My questions:
1) Is there a way to achieve the above more rigorously than using dir? 
2) What does "interesting set of names" mean and how is it computed?

Comment: the solution might depend on why do you need it.

Comment: Do you want a Python 2 answer, a Python 3 answer, or both? I just noticed that you tagged the question Python 3, but you linked Python 2 documentation. My answer was written with Python 2 in mind; some of it is a little different in Python 3, mostly where the code is and how much deprecated stuff needs to be handled.

Comment: sorry, yes, was looking for python3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kind of?

With custom `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` implementations, an object can dynamically respond to requests for any attribute. You could have an object that has *every* attribute, or an object that randomly has or doesn't have the `foo` attribute with 50% probability every time you look at it. If you know how an object's `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` work, and you know that they respond to a finite list of attribute names, then you can write your own version of `dir` that lists everything, but even handling the basic built-in types requires an uncomfortable number of cases. You can see the `dir` implementation in [`Objects/object.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9f4b066754c3/Objects/object.c#l1678).

2. The documentation gives an explanation of which attributes are considered interesting:

   - If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the module’s attributes.
   - If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.
   - Otherwise, the list contains the object’s attributes’ names, the names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

By "attributes", this documentation is mostly referring to the keys of its `__dict__`. There's also some handling for `__members__` and `__methods__`; those are deprecated, and I don't remember what they do.